# Payload-cms pdf icon

Tags: typescript, payload-cms

I use `Payloadcms`, I created a collection for downloading `PDF` files, can you tell me how to set up the icon?

```js
...
  upload: {
    staticDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../documents'),
    mimeTypes: ['application/pdf'],
  },
...
```

where the cursor is

[image]